# How to serve a local file instead of the real resource with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I'm trying to create E2E tests for my web app with puppeteer.
I would like to run in my public domain with local js files, so I get the full public behavior and only the js is the result of my local build.

I know how to intercept the requests for the js bundles, but looking at the request.respond documentation I couldn't quit understand how to serve a different file from the local drive

Comment: Create a local live server and load it?

Comment: That's how I develop locally, but when I run e2e in CI build, I want to load the production URL with my branch code, instead of running in localhost

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, it works even if it's not the best way.
It allows running e2e tests in CI build with the branch js bundles. 
After intercepting the js bundle request, I abort it.
Than I insert a script tag, with path to the local js bundle, relative to project root -

```js
page.on('request', async interceptedRequest => {
      const url = interceptedRequest.url()
      if (jsBundleRegex.test(url)) {
        const fullLocalFileName = findMatchingBundleFileName(url)
        await page.addScriptTag({
          path: `./build/static/js/${fullLocalFileName}`
        })
        interceptedRequest.abort()
      } else {
        interceptedRequest.continue()
      }
```